# Is avoiding HTML form in this way right?

Tags: html, forms, jquery, validation

Trying to avoid HTML form in the following way :

Instead of

```
<form action="submit_now.php" method="POST" name="my_form">

<input type="text" value="" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

trying to use :

```
<input type="text" value="" />
<button value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Reasons:
   For the proposed second way, I do not need any jQuery form [plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) like thing to tame the form to be submitted without redirection. Rather, on clicking the button I can do the client side validation and then send inputs to server side validation through an ajax call.

Is the reason not to use the second way all about the hidden fields as their values   might be visible in the ajax params?

Comment: In a form you can use `onsubmit="code"` to specify what happens when the form is submitted, just like you can with an `onclick` handler on the button.

Comment: But after the `onsubmit` code , the submission takes place in the usual way .

Comment: Not if it returns `false`. That's how `onANYTHING` handlers prevent the default action.

Comment: if it returns `true` , then won't the form be submitted in the usual way ?

Comment: Yes. That's how validation functions work, for instance. They return true if successful, false if there's a validation error.

Comment: let me test that . However, that probably does not provide any answer to the question in the OP .

Comment: Which is why I didn't post it as an answer, just a comment. I think your question is based on a false premise.

Comment: You wrote _Reasons: For the proposed second way, I do not need any jQuery form plugin like thing_. But you don't need a plugin for the first way, either, you just need to write a submit handler that returns false. Other than that, it can be identical to the click handler for the button.